# Need help publishing my new iOS application

Tags: ios

I need help publishing my new iOS application. I already published the Android version but the iOS requires me to pay 100 USD but the fact is I don't have that much money to pay for just testing the application.

Please help me publish my app.

Comment: You can install your app on your own device for testing without payment. If you want to distribute your app in the App Store you need to pay.

Comment: This question does not belong here

Comment: Alec, why not?  This is a very valid question.

Comment: If you don't want to pay money to apple, don't use their product(s) ... And I agree that this question is off-topic.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It doesn't belong on this site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to have a developer license to publish an app to the app store, so you have to pay $100.  There MIGHT be a discount for students. There is no other way around it, sorry.  Blame apple for that.